# Hey Guys Girls, so who Tweets here?

Tags: social-network, social, websites, contact

Was wondering who tweets here, I have been trying to follow people in my industry. Twitter took me a little time to actually see a need/benefit but i feel it does have both. So what your thoughts?

UPDATE: if i had looked at the top of the page i would have seen the twitter link, doh!

anyway HI!

Comment: @ALL, @Ryanhdd, @Andrew, I'm trying to get this going: #prototips. I suggested that people share things about Pro Tools, like shortcuts, workflows and other tricks. It could be a rich and easy to reach resource, virtually ever expanding. Ding!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just SPAM

Answer (score 2):

You guys win. I've joined twitter. Bring on the revolution in my life.

@urbanaudiosteve

Comment: Ha ha :D You have to try...

Comment: yeah, I just joined too thx to this thread.  How come there's a thousand steve urbans on twitter?

Comment: everybody wants to be me? LOL!

Comment: 2 months and 1 week in, I love twitter. If for nothing other than the AES coverage from all of you. Twitter rocks.

Answer (score 2):

@goaliedrummer

Alerts to updates on my blog, and lots of other audio stuff that comes across my plate.

Comment: Yea, lets try and keep this to one thread? Makes it easier to find everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I love twitter - lots of great and inspiring links and contacts!

@lydrummet

Answer (score 1):

Great application for getting the newest scoop from sound people. Always interesting to read what my fellow partners in crime are up to.

@soundwizard

Answer (score 1):

Good idea for a thread! I look forward to following everyone!

@arrowheadaudio
@F_Pearson

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

@gglencross

See you there!

Gillian

Answer (score 1):

mine is @edwinmatthews

Answer (score 0):

I find it quiet a useful resource of information and a great of getting to know people from far and distant lands. Made a number of friends there over the last few months.

@ianjamespalmer

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has been an incredible resource for me, both in gaining new friends in this field AND just for getting feedback on anything in general.

@_joethomas

Answer (score 0):

Same as you @Ryanhdd, took me a while. I came, I saw, I let go, eventually SSD got me back in :)

@justinhuss

Answer (score 0):

Have been quiet on posting lately, but I agree - definitely nice to build a community of audioheads!

@joelraabe

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is so cool!

@misazam @designingsound :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm on there too. I agree it's an awesome resource for picking brains and getting support/inspiration/info.

@surfyournut

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is a brilliant social and marketing tool.

@owenprice

Answer (score 0):

@chuck_Russom. Be warned, I'm known to rant at times :)

Answer (score 0):

@toxicbag_joe. I'm there when I can be. Hopefully I say something interesting now and then.

Answer (score 0):

|  <3  t w i t t e r

[@soundplusdesign](http://twitter.com/soundplusdesign)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used twitter much on a professional level, but if you want to see my personal comments I'm [@matneyx](http://twitter.com/matneyx).

Answer (score 0):

@timprebble

In the early days of twitter it was always funny to hear strong opinions about it from people who had never used it... like many things you have to use it for a while to appreciate how and why it is interesting

Answer (score 0):

@ragamesound is me.

Answer (score 0):

@noisejockey, natch!

Answer (score 0):

@sepulchra  I've been known to tweet and retweet.

Answer (score 0):

@amazingrolo

wooo.

Answer (score 0):

@danflosdorf is me!

Answer (score 0):

@fabio_iaci

on sound, devastating italian politics and nonsense

Answer (score 0):

@ntkeep

Twitter is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

@engineaudio

It's where I am at!

Answer (score 0):

@jeffreypfisher

Always something industry related on my tweets!

--jpf

Answer (score 0):

Hi all!

I recently joined tweeter, I find it useful to discover other people involved with sound & sound design i could not  know of otherwise. Anyway: tiquetonnesound on twitter, that´s me. (still under construction...)

Answer (score 0):

ok, i caved. @DynInterference

i'll probably mostly use it for my site, but who knows what i'll do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all! I´m new at twitter too. I´m at @inigoegido.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there! You can follow me at @hugoverweij

See you on Twitter ;)

Answer (score 0):

@dieffe

see you all on twitter! :)

davide

Answer (score 0):

@jamesdbryant

Took me some time to see the benefit too, but joined recently, and have discovered it's great! Useful and inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

Hey everyone! Find me:

@alansende

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow me at [@cvrgoje](http://twitter.com/#!/cvrgoje/)

See you on Twitter :)

Nikola

Answer (score 0):

@a_millington here :)

Answer (score 0):

@MixingManiac

Loves the twitter.

Answer (score 0):

@phonetical

I go back and forth with it.

Answer (score 0):

@1000machines
   ...see you there ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can find me as @synsynth

Answer (score 0):

@C3Sound

I use it, but mainly just for leaving messages to people who dont use linkedin or facebook

Sometimes ill throw up links and such.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to know when I farted or what it smelt like and don't mind a ton of links to youtube videos..

follow me [@StephenSaldanha](http://twitter.com/StephenSaldanha)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't updated or tweeted much but i hope to in the coming months to talk about various projects I'll be working on. 
Cheers! 
KTCSound
www.KTCSound.com

Answer (score 0):

@bmoyle here

TIme to create a new list I think :-)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Twitter @bilekt3

Answer (score 0):

@colinhart

Love twitter

Answer (score 0):

Twitter rocks!!
[@sisound](http://twitter.com/#/sisound) is me.

Mostly about sound but other random things do find their way into the feed. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

@arrowheadaudio and @F_Pearson.

Don't tweet too much at the moment (I'm pretty new to the whole thing) but am planning on getting on it soon!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

@gglencross

See you soon!

Gillian

Answer (score 0):

great.
I'm @pushformono

Answer (score 0):

Aye, im on twitter.

@_earTrumpet

thanks guys,

Answer (score 0):

thesoundmonster

Hope to see some you...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am @theaudiogeek

Answer (score 0):

[@blynkmusic](http://twitter.com/blynkmusic) & [@makenoiseuk](http://twitter.com/makenoiseuk) are both me!

Answer (score 0):

My twitter account is @DJ_Rx

Answer (score 0):

Just added most of you guys at my sound_design list on twitter! @nikolasx . twitter is an awesome tool too use! and i believe it has not shown its full potential yet, people will find new ways to use this tool soon...

Answer (score 0):

@ragamesound

I also tweet about experimental game stuff a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've never really got the point of twitter, but so many of you have been so vocal about it's virtues that I've just setup an account.  You can follow me @SoundSculpting

Answer (score 0):

You can find me at @[insomaniac](http://twitter.com/insomaniac), and I'm starting up a project @[analogjitter](http://twitter.com/analogjitter) that should come into use soon.

Answer (score 0):

I held out on jumping aboard the Twitter Wagon for as long as I could stand it.

@Cavanaudio

Answer (score 0):

@map_a_mundi

field recording, architecture, aural cartography, design

Answer (score 0):

@shermanonline

See you in the twitter verse!